# Шорткод появляется над контентом, как исправить?

Tags: php, wordpress

Создал свой шорткод, но он почему-то выводится на странице над всем контентом. Как исправить?

```
add_shortcode( 'gallery_page', 'shortcode_gallery_page' );

function shortcode_gallery_page() {
    ob_start();

    get_template_part( 'template-gallery' );

    return "ob_get_clean()";
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
add_shortcode( 'gallery_page', 'shortcode_gallery_page' );

function shortcode_gallery_page() {
    ob_start();

    get_template_part( 'template-gallery' );

    return ob_get_clean();
}
```